# Conversion failed when dealing with ambiguous varchar (uniqueidentifier or not) in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Users are allowed to send in a reference to a Scheme by either the scheme's id or the scheme's name. If the given scheme is found in the records as an id or as a name, the data is valid. The temp table...

```
CREATE TABLE #ModelsForScheme( 
[modelid] uniqueidentifier,  
[schemeid] VARCHAR (36))
```

Temp table is later populated. What I have now...

```
DECLARE @XMLScheme VARCHAR (36)
SET @XMLScheme = (SELECT TOP 1 schemeid FROM #ModelsForScheme) --there will only be one row

DECLARE @SchemeID VARCHAR (36)
SELECT @SchemeID=schemeid FROM SCHEMES WHERE schemeid=@XMLScheme
IF @SchemeID IS NULL
  SELECT @SchemeID=schemeid FROM SCHEMES WHERE [name]=@XMLScheme

IF @SchemeID IS NULL
  SELECT 'Scheme is NULL'
```

(the column `schemeid` is a `uniqueidentifier` in the table `SCHEMES`).

This works fine when a `uniqueidentifier` is sent. But when a name is sent (e.g. `@XMLScheme = 'dog'`), I get the following error;

> *Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.*

I have tried `CAST` and `CONVERT`, but I can not get them to work. If I were guaranteed the was only one scheme in `SCHEMES` I could get it to work but that is not the case.

```
SET @XMLSchemeID = (SELECT TOP 1 schemeid FROM #ModelsForScheme)
SET @SchemeID= (SELECT TOP 1 schemeid FROM SCHEMES)
IF @XMLSchemeID<>@SchemeID
  Select 'yeaaaaa no error'
```

Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following IF to check if @XMLScheme is an uid or a string.

```
DECLARE @XMLScheme VARCHAR (36)
SET @XMLScheme = (SELECT TOP 1 schemeid FROM #ModelsForScheme) --there will only be one row

DECLARE @SchemeID VARCHAR (36)

IF @XMLScheme like replace('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','0','[a-fA-F0-9]')
   SELECT @SchemeID=schemeid FROM SCHEMES WHERE schemeid=@XMLScheme
ELSE
  SELECT @SchemeID=schemeid FROM SCHEMES WHERE [name]=@XMLScheme;


IF @SchemeID IS NULL
  SELECT 'Scheme is NULL'
```

Comment: From the question "(the column schemeid is a uniqueidentifier in the table SCHEMES)" so it's not a numeric.

Comment: Fixed with a like statement to check if it is uid.

Answer (score 2):

Your query fails because

```
.... WHERE schemeid=@XMLScheme
```

does an implicit type conversion from `varchar(36)` to `uniqueidentifier` on `@XMLScheme`

You can test if `@XMLScheme` is a valid `uniqueidentifier` before executing the query.

```
if (@XMLScheme like '________-____-____-____-____________' and patindex('%[^-0-9A-F]%', @XMLScheme) = 0)
  SELECT @SchemeID=schemeid FROM SCHEMES WHERE schemeid=@XMLScheme
```